# How a F5 can handle multiple virtual IP address on different network?

Tags: f5-big-ip

I'm confusing when design an F5 system. I have to using F5 with two networks subnet, for each network we need a virtual IP. The problem is F5 have only one default gateway so I only can choose one of those networks router as default gw and the packet cannot back to client on another net.
On A10 I used aVCS to deal with this problem, but not sure F5 BigIP have same feature.
I'm consider using Direct return but not sure it's correct way.

Please share your idea.

Thank you very much,
Gk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route Domains can be used as Theo has indicated, but it's not necessary. You can just add a virtual server in a separate subnet to vlan of choice and it will arp accordingly to requests. For return traffic, auto-lasthop will handle any requests. For any traffic initiated, will need to rely on the default route or build source-based routing into a policy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your TMOS version, F5 has support for Route Domains, which allow you to use multiple gateways by logically separating different subnets/virtual servers--I use this to separate my DMZ traffic from my internal traffic.

LINK (TMOS 11.4): [Working with Route Domains](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-ip-routing-administration-11-4-0/2.html)

Once route domains are created, you can specify which route domain your virtual servers and nodes will use using the format:

> <IP>%<RDID>

For example, if your VIP is 10.10.10.10 and your route domain ID is 2, then use:

> 10.10.10.10%2

In addition, you can place route domains in their own Partition (LINK: [Working with Partitions](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-concepts-11-4-0/8.html)), which is only administrative but makes it easy to remember in which network you are working.